# How do I add a custom discount filter to Shopify using the Palo Alto theme?

Tags: shopify

I am using Alto version 4.6.3, I added a custom discount filter like 10% 20% 30%...

I tried using JavaScript to filter the products... But I have faced an issue:

**Product not showing**

After clicking, the filter works fine but is not visible. I can click but the product is not visible. But after scrolling all the products it is visible and works well.

First, I tried integrating the discount filter inside the default filter. But after clicking on other filters the javascript of the discount filter doesn't work...

[Screenshot of invisible product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmNPP.jpg)

**collection.liquid**

```
<label for="discount-filter">Discount</label>
<div class="discount-list" id="discount-list">
  <div class="discount-item">
    <div class="discount-circle" data-discount="">All</div>
  </div>
  <div class="discount-item">
    <div class="discount-circle" data-discount="10">10%</div>
  </div>
  <div class="discount-item">
    <div class="discount-circle" data-discount="20">20%</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**theme.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.discount-circle').click(function () {
        $('.discount-circle').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        const selectedDiscount = $(this).data('discount');
        filterDiscounts(selectedDiscount);
    });

    const selectedDiscount = $('.discount-circle.selected').data('discount');
    filterDiscounts(selectedDiscount);

});

  function filterDiscounts(selectedDiscount) {
      $('.product-grid-item').each(function () {
          var productDiscount = parseInt($(this).data('discount'));
          if (selectedDiscount === '') {
              $(this).show();
          } else {
              var lowerBound = selectedDiscount;
              var upperBound = selectedDiscount + 9;
              if (productDiscount >= lowerBound && productDiscount <= upperBound) {
                  $(this).show();
              } else {
                  $(this).hide();
              }
          }
      });
  }
```

**product-grid-item.liquid**

```
{% assign price = product.price %}
{% assign price_compare = product.compare_at_price %}
{% assign price_difference = price_compare | minus: price %}
{% assign percent_off = price_difference | times: 1.00 | divided_by: price_compare | times: 100 %}
{% assign discount = percent_off | floor | append: '%'%}

<span class="product-discount-percentage">
 {{ discount }}
</span\>
```

```
<div class="product-grid-item" data-discount="{{ discount }}">
 // products render html
</div>
```